# How can I remove comma, full stop and semicolon between two code tags in a string?

Tags: python, nlp

I have a string(a Javadoc comment) that contains `<code>...</code>` tags. It looks something like this,

```
<code>System.out</code>.
@param project The project to display a description of.
Must not be <code>null;</code>.
```

I want to be able to remove comma(,), full stop(.) and semi-colon(;) between the `<code>..</code>` tags.

It should look something like this:

```
<code>Systemout</code>.
@param project The project to display a description of.
Must not be <code>null</code>.
```

I have tried the following:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

var = '''Prints the description of a project (if there is one) to
        <code>System.out</code>.
        @param project The project to display a description of.
        Must not be <code>null;</code>.'''

soup = BeautifulSoup(var, 'html.parser')

for a in soup.find_all('code'):
  print (a.string)
```

But this is extracting the text in between. I don't really know to remove the comma, full stop, and semicolon and append it back to the original string. Any help will be greatly appreciated!

**SOLUTION**

```
matches =  re.sub('<code>(.*?)</code>', lambda m: "<code>{}</code>".format( m.group(1).replace(".","").replace(",","").replace(";","")), var, flags=re.DOTALL)
```

Comment: Well - whats wrong with your code that tries to solve it? Where is your code that tries to solve this? Please post a [mcve] and specify your problem.

Comment: Got it, thanks! Updating it.

Comment: @PatrickArtner please check now. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Read the file  with an HTML parser like [this built-in one](https://docs.python.org/3/library/html.parser.html). [Do not try](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/) to identify the code tags with regular expressions! Then the removal can be done with `s.replace(".","").replace(",","").replace(";","")`

Comment: Hi! Thanks! I have updated my code and I am using beautifulsoup. I just dont know how to remove the comma, fullstop and semicolon extracted text between the tags and append it back to the original string.

Comment: OK, I I explained how to remove those characters.

As to how to append it back ... how are you writing the new (altered)  HTML  file?

Comment: To append it back, its literally the same string but without those characters(",",".",";") between the tags, since I need to do some more text processing later on.

Comment: Just append s.replace(".","").replace(",","").replace(";","")

Comment: Thanks, I used this. Please see the solution in my question.